# Export Shapefile for a custom region

Tags: shapefile, google-maps

Is there any way to export a region on Google maps to a shapefile or any other format?

For example, I have the following region on Google Maps, and I wish to export it to shapefile.

[image: Google Maps]

Comment: What do you want? The roads? The place names? The points-of-interest? The shading? The rivers? How is all of that going to fit into a shapefile? Even apart from the legal aspect (this is Google's data) the technical aspect is hard - Google's maps are rasters.

Comment: I just need the boundary, marked in red in the image.

Comment: Can't you convert the .kml to .shp using QGIS/ArcMAP etc?

Comment: I do not have any kml. All i have is the region plotted by google maps. It would be helpful if i could export it to kml too.

Comment: Firstly I would find out if the boundary was available as an open data set from another source. Even tracing outlines from Google maps can breach the usage terms.

Comment: I have less than 15 reputation so I can not add comments. I did as indicated: went to google earth drew a polygon saved it as kml then went to qgis and viewed my polygon, and there's no map. Only a drawing of the polygon. I have the same need as OP, I want to be able to go to google maps/earth and extract the political boundaries of an area. There must be a way because google maps has information of these boundaries in their website. They must have the shapefiles, question is: how do we get them?

Comment: welcome to GIS SE! There is no way because google don't publish their vector source but a rendering of it. Even so, it is more appropriate that you initiate a new question (you can even quote this post in your question) instead of adding an answer that is not such.

Answer (score 3):

Open Google Earth and plot the polygon you want:

[image]

Then right click and save as a type .kml.

[image]

Now you need to convert to .shp using QGIS, or in ESRI ArcMAP use the *KML to Layer* tool.